# S3 + Lambda + Cloudfront permissions model setup problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

CDK questions are always hard to ask. I have an s3 bucket and a cloudfront CDN to serve it. There is also a Lambda function that runs code to put files in the bucket but the lambda logs are reporting ERROR AccessDenied: Access Denied at Request.extractError when they try to write.

**How can I allow my lambda processes to access the bucket but prevent unauthorized access from cloudfront?**

I can't share my CDK code without obfuscating it but here's the gist of it:

```js
        const myBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, `CDNBucket`, {
            bucketName: `mybucketname`,
            publicReadAccess: false
        })

        const originAccessIdentity = new cloudfront.OriginAccessIdentity(scope, 'CDNIdentity')

        const myBucketPolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['s3:GetObject'],
            principals: [
                new iam.CanonicalUserPrincipal(
                    originAccessIdentity.cloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityS3CanonicalUserId
                )
            ],
            resources: [myBucket.bucketArn + '/*']
        })
        myBucket.addToResourcePolicy(myBucketPolicy)

        const lambdaWatcher = new lambda.Function(this, `MyFunctionName`, {
            code: new lambda.AssetCode(lambdaNodePath),
            functionName: 'MyFunctionName',
            handler: 'lambda.handler',
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
        })
        props.buckets.myBucket.grantReadWrite(this.lambdaWatcher)

        const cloudFrontWebDistribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(
            this,
            `Web_CDN`,
            {
                comment: `CDN distribution`,
                originConfigs: [
                    {
                        s3OriginSource: {
                            s3BucketSource: myBucket,
                            originAccessIdentity: originAccessIdentity
                        },
                        behaviors: [
                            {
                                isDefaultBehavior: true,
                                compress: true,
                                minTtl: cdk.Duration.seconds(0),
                                maxTtl: cdk.Duration.days(365),
                                defaultTtl: cdk.Duration.days(1)
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
```

The bucket policy that is generated is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the Lambda policy generated is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:Abort*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a red herring here. `grantReadWrite` doesn't include ACL so I needed `grantPutAcl` as well.